# How to read this graph input and put into an adjacency matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, graph, adjacency-matrix, floyd-warshall

I am confused and trying to figure out how to put this graph data into an adjacency matrix.

This is some sample input from a text file:

```
0 1,28 3,33
1 2,10 4,44
2 3,50
3 4,30
4
```

This is how the matrix should look

```
  0   1   2   3   4
0 INF 28  INF 33  INF
1 28  INF 10  INF 44 
2 INF 10  INF 50  INF 
3 33  INF 50  30  INF  
4 INF 44  INF INF INF
```

This would be some sort of multidimensional array but I'm lost on how to translate the input into one. Any help would be appreciated.

I am working in python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straight forward,

for x x1,y1 x2,y2 input

it means that

> there is edge between x and x1 with value y1 and  edge x and x2 with value y2.

To parse it, do this

> 1: use space separator to split the dataset.
>   2: First element in the resulting array is your node(x).
>   3: for i (1 to n), do a split by comma(,), which will give an array of two elements, with first element being node(x1) and second being distance y(1).
>   4: To set the value in matrix for each pair, mat[x,x1]=y1

Edit
It appears that your graph is a undirected garph. So for each pair, you have to do

> mat[x,x1]=y1
>   mat[x1,x]=y1